# Понимание MVC и MVP

Tags: javafx, mvc, mvp

В `MVC` пользовательский ввод приходит на контроллер, затем контроллер изменяет модель, а она в свою очередь рассылает события на подписанные представления.

Нестыковки, которые меня смущают:

1. Получается, что контроллер никак напрямую не взаимодействует с представлением. Это так?
2. Невозможность реализации `MVC` в таких библиотеках, как например `JavaFX`, т.к. там ввод приходит в представление (на мой взгляд представление ультра-тонкое, и вероятно `JavaFX` это про `MVP`?). Так ли это?

В `MVP` же ввод приходит на представление, т.к. представление тонкое, то все события "передаются" контроллеру, тот изменяет модель, а затем изменяет представление.

Правильно ли я понимаю эти концепции?